# Db2 migrate data from row in one table to column in other table

Tags: sql, db2, data-migration

I have a schema that look like this

```
table 1
-------
ID TYPE VALUE
==============
1 A 10
1 B 200
2 A 20
2 B 500


table 2
-------------
ID typeA typeB
==============
1 10 200
2 20 500
```

My migration script is

```
update table2 set typeA = (select t1.value from table1 t1 
where t1.ID = table2.ID and t1.type = 'A'),
typeB = (select t1.value from table1 t1 where t1.ID = table2.ID and t1.type='B');
```

Now it works fine when there are two types for each id, and fails with sql error code [407](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes/src/tpc/n407.htm) if row for a type is missing. I tried using IFNULL, COALESCE but nothing seems to work. I know this is a problem that must have been solved many times but couldn't get a direct answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE` should work for you, does this give you an error?

```
update table2 t2
set typeA = COALESCE((select t1.value
                        from table1 t1
                       where t1.ID = t2.ID
                         and t1.type = 'A'), 0),
    typeB = COALESCE((select t1.value
                        from table1 t1
                       where t1.ID = t2.ID
                         and t1.type='B'), 0);
```